# Dynamically call a javascript function, imported from another module, by name

Tags: javascript, function, import

I'm trying to make some "dynamic" API calls while retrieving some API call templates from a DB.

So what I have to work with is the module name, the function name inside the module and some args to pass on.

And I would like to do something like this :

```
import someModule;

let someModuleName = "someModule";
let someModuleFunctionName = "someModuleFunction"; // someModuleFunction is declared inside someModule


someModuleName.someModuleFunctionName(args);
```

I tried to use brackets notation and also apply() with no success.

I must say I am a complete beginner in JS and not a professional coder.

Any thoughts ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

try

```
import {someModuleFunction} from './someModule'
// the path is to be changed to match yours
```

let say we have a modules.js file with one simple add function

```
const add(a,b)=> a+b
```

to import and call the function you'll do this :

```
import {add} from '.modules"
console.log(add(1,4))
```

Comment: Hi, this is not exactly what I want, I want to be able to call a function by its name and this function is part of a module. I need to be able to "retrieve" the module by its name as well. I know this will work : someModule[someFunctionName](args) but I don't know how I can reference "someModule" by its name

Answer (score 0):

Sort it out this way :

First import the module as an object dynamically with the path built from "static" strings (not working with only variables see: https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/) and my module name :

```
const APIlibrary = await import(`path_prefix_to_modules${this.someModuleName}.js`);
```

Then find the proper APICall (function of the module) in the object (not sure it's the best way...):

```
const arrayOfAPIFunctions = Object.entries(APIlibrary.default);
const indexOfAPIFunction = arrayOfAPIFunctions.findIndex(x => x[0] == this.someAPICallName);
const APIFunction = arrayOfAPIFunctions[indexOfAPIFunction][1];
```

Finally make the API call:

```
APIFunction(args...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval function, but be carefully for javascript injection vulnerability!

```
eval('var dynamicFunction = ' + someModuleName + '.' + someModuleFunctionName);
dynamicFunction(args);
```

if the content of the variables "someModuleName" and "someModuleFunctionName" are not controlled by you or by some that you trust (like client users), they can inject arbitrary js code that will run, and introduce the vulnerability!

Anyway, it's good practice in this case validate the variables contents, to make sure that will have only valid values, for example only allowing alphanumeric chars,  underscore and dollar for the module and function name.